# Expo code changes by itself after I'm saving it

Tags: reactjs, expo

does someone know, why after I save my expo project, the code itself changes and leads to a syntax error on my android emulator..I also tried to save it manually but after I press save, the code Stiller changes.

I also verfied the settings for formatting.

Comment: since it's editor-related, what editor are you using? either disable format on save or find the default linter/formatter and fix its settings for the language your using, also it would help to show what error/s you're getting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.